# Script for ssh automatic login to a specific port

Tags: ssh, scripting, python, perl, autologin

So currently, the "traditional" way to connect through SSH is the following one:

```
ssh USERNAME@HOST -p PORT
```

I would like to create a script in which I will include all the appropriate information (username, password, host, port) and when I run it, it will connect automatically leading me to the shell of the host machine.

I don't care about the language you will use (e.g. Python, Perl...). I have tried to create it using Expect but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: is for your self? create a bashrc alias

Comment: A better option might be to use the user's `~/.ssh/config` file + key-based authentication

Comment: you are right, I didn't think about it

Answer (score 2):

For automatic login, the way to go is using key-based authentication.

A nice tutorial [here](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password)

You can then use the default one (the one in the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` ) or use another key passing `-i MyKeyFile` parameter to ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sshpass`

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Create your script

```
#!/bin/bash

user="user"
psswd="password"
port="22"
host="domain.com"

sshpass -p $psswd ssh $user@$host -p $port
```

Execute

```
$ bash connect_script.bash
Welcome to Ubuntu ..... LTS (.......)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
New release '14.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

You have new mail.
Last login: Thu Jan 21 11:39:35 2016 from x.x.x.x
user@host:~$
```